# Agregar / Ocultar clase .active con toogle en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hola a todos tengo la siguiente estructuta HTML

```
<div class="flags_wrapper">
        <div class="flag active">
            <img src="assets/icons/spain48.png" alt="es">
        </div>
        <div class="flag">
            <img src="assets/icons/gb48.png" alt="gb">
        </div>
</div>
```

Y el siguiente código CSS

```
.flag{display: none;}
.flag.active{display:block}
```

Lo que busco es que al hacer click en el div flag con la clase active, ésta cambie al div que no la tiene, produciendo así el efecto de cambiar las banderas al hacer click, alternando la bandera de España con la bandera de Gran Bretaña, en función del click.

He probado con el siguiente código JS pero claro, solo me quita / añade la clase .active en un div, no lo alterna entre los 2 div, no sé muy bien como podría hacerlo, se os ocurre algo? Gracias.

```
 var flag = document.querySelectorAll('.flag');

for (let i = 0; i<flag.length; i++){
    flag[i].addEventListener('click', ()=>{
        flag[i].classList.toggle('active')
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que no puedes hacer click en un elemento oculto. Por eso al ocultar en el que haces click, no se muestra ni se mostrará el otro.

Con este código te funciona, pero solo si hay 2 elementos. Si hubiera 3 elementos deberías replantearte el funcionamiento:

```
var flag = document.querySelectorAll('.flag');
flag.forEach((x,index) => {
    x.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
        x.classList.toggle("active");
        flag.forEach((y, indexY) => {
            if(index !== indexY){
                y.classList.toggle("active");
            }
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: Hola! Pues sí, tu código funciona pero le tengo que dar un buen repaso porque no entiendo muy bien que está haciendo esos 2 forEach, esos parámetros me refiero. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Pues cuando haces el queryselectorall, el resulado es un array de elementos. el primer foreach recorre los elementos y el parametro x es cada uno de esos elementos . el segundo foreach lo recorres para buscar todos los elementos que no sean iguales al que hiciste click para añadirle/quitarle la clase active

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacer lo siguiente:

- Suscribir el evento `click` al selector `.flags_wrapper`
- Buscar buscar los `.flag` hijos de este
- Recorrerlos y hacer el `toggle`.

#### Ejemplo:

```js
document.querySelector('.flags_wrapper')
  .addEventListener('click', (e) => { //<- Suscribimos el evento
    e.currentTarget.querySelectorAll('.flag') // <- Buscamos los flag
      .forEach(e => e.classList.toggle('active')) //<- Hacemos el toggle
  })
```

```css
.flag { display: none; }
.flag.active { display: block; }
```

```html
<div class="flags_wrapper">
  <div class="flag active">
    <img src="assets/icons/spain48.png" alt="es">
  </div>
  <div class="flag">
    <img src="assets/icons/gb48.png" alt="gb">
  </div>
</div>
```